# How to safely determine if an external link points to a legitimate website?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

For example, I encountered a link to **flovverbasket.com** in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248677/i-am-trying-to-implement-product-carousel-using-owl-carosuel-but-this-is-not-wor#comment52377669_32248677) <sup>10k+</sup>, and didn't want to click, since it seems so much like a homograph attack for **flowerbasket.com**.  Assuming that it wasn't a legitimate site, I flagged the comment as spam, but the flag was rejected.  Google seems to have indexed it, and there are some associated Google+ and Twitter accounts, but none with any significant activity posted.

Is there any safe and objective way to confirm whether this is actually a legitimate site?

Comment: The OP's attitude doesn't help matters. Either they have something to hide, or they don't and are just that uninterested in getting help with a legitimate issue. Either way the question isn't answerable.

Comment: @BoltClock It's not a great question at any rate, but I was willing to chalk up OP's tone to non-native English.  I didn't actually find it particularly off-putting, just an attempt to clarify, though I don't think my point about the mis-tagging really made it across.

Comment: The site itself doesn't look like spam, it just looks like a website in progress.

Comment: Even if it appears "in progress", it may already be ridden with exploits right now. Or in near future. You won't even notice, until your machine starts to spread malware, that's how things work.

Comment: I used to use [SiteAdvisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McAfee_SiteAdvisor) when I used a Windows machine, but that was several years ago.

Answer (score 14):

The web is a dangerous place. No foolproof way is available to do what you are
asking. Even the best tools available are only giving you extra layers of
protection. Having said that I find these tools to be very effective day to day:

- [uBlock Origin](http://alternativeto.net/software/ublock-origin)

  This blocks most ads. In addition, it utilizes a known bad site blocklist.
  Either of these features can be disabled on a per site basis, so you have
  control over how much protection you want.
- [NoScript](http://alternativeto.net/software/noscript)

  This blocks all JavaScript on all domains. If you prefer, you can add a
  whitelist of approved sites, or temp allow permissions for a site. Again, you
  have control over the amount of protection.

Comment: A similar list as uBlock, but intended to be used as a [hosts file replacement](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm).  Personally, I find that any site in this list is going to make my day more annoying.

Comment: What, no mention of [RequestPolicy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/), which blocks all cross-domain requests by default?  (makes much of the web unusable, until you manually activate the few domains that need requests passed through).

Comment: @Yakk cross-domain requests are not inherently unsafe. Plus they can be easily bypassed with CORS proxy or similar. Same-origin is just a shitty rule that I would like to see go away, I certainly am not going to advocate addons that police it

Answer (score 12):

I've often run into this -- you want to check a website to see if it's spam but you don't want to click on it in case it has malware. The best solution I've come up with is to check a link with a malware/security scanner before actually visiting with my browser.

For the example you've provided, the sucuri scanner (one of many I found with a quick google search) [didn't detect malware](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/flovverbasket.com):

[image]

Obviously these reports are not 100% accurate or foolproof, but this is usually enough to make me comfortable visiting the site. At this point, I would just visit to website and determine for myself whether the link belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Virustotal.com is also able to do that: [Scan of flovverbasket.com](https://www.virustotal.com/url/86c5b484251849a3cf8c6936bf1757cd47f52b682d8c6634a48448b7f0c15a8c/analysis/1441554900/)

Comment: Using malware scanner is a good idea, but relying on it to "make oneself comfortable" when visiting suspicious site is laughable. Scanners are by definition unable to detect zero-day threats, and those are the only things, that can breach defenses of modern up-to-date browsers. At least disable Javascript and plugins beforehand!

Comment: @user1643723 I guess we should all just unplug our computers and go outside...

Comment: @MikeD. or just disable JS, Flash, Java, Acrobat and similar exploit-ridden plugins and use a secure OS, like of the *nix family.

Comment: @NewWorld, disable JS? And how [jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/278654) will work?! -1 for you.